Consistency between parents around bedtime routine
We have a 10mo who sleeps solidly 11h at night. Almost always cries when going to bed but usually asleep within 5-10min. Quite a happy kid so we reckon the cry is just tired or FOMO. We have a routine, put into cot awake, bum pat and say goodnight.
Dad sits in a chair in the dark in the far end of room (and she can see him a bit I reckon) and is on his phone, she falls asleep. I disappear into the walk in robe where she can’t see me, she falls asleep. If she can’t fall asleep herself and cries out after 3-4min we bum pat her and say goodnight phrase again. We haven’t needed to do extra pats too often.

do dad and I need to do the same thing after pats and goodnight ie either the chair or the wardrobe to maintain consistency? Or does it not matter as long as we go to her in the same reassuring way and do the same pats if she needs it?

I would like to be able to work on us leaving the room eventually but dad is hesitant as this change has cause the settle to take a longer time and he’s not ready, and he thinks she’s not ready either. How did you know when your baby was ‘ready’ for this transition?



The key part is consistancy. In my experience both parent dont need to do the same thing, but in broad lines they should.
We both read a bed time story, but we act out the story in different manners. I put on his clothes while he is lying on his back, his mom while he stands. She sing a song while brushing teeth, I make funny sounds.
That seems different, but the important parts:

the routine start about the same time every time
We both shower/bath with him (might as well, save a little energy and its fun)
Followed by putting on the sleeping bag
Read a short story (and then per his request always another)
We place him in bed and say goodnight
We leave the room

It's a bit unique that you hide in a closet. You should both just leave the room in a consistent way. I doubt it'd do anything negatively. If anything the baby might fall asleep and then wake up because you're leaving and make some noice.
IMO you should lay the child to bed, say something affectionate (or whatever you like) and then clearly leave. It should not be a surprise that you are gone. Its a much more odd experience that before you fall asleep your parents are there, and then when you wake up they're gone?! What happend?! Where are they?! If you obviously leave, that is more obvious.
In our case this took 3 days. We left and only came back after 10 minutes. I cant recall from where, but there is something magic about 8 minutes with babies, your 3-4mins is too short.
It made us feel bad, leaving him to cry, but we both knew that this is in both our interests. The parents need to sleep, and the sooner the child can sleep solo, the better it rests too.
The first night it took 2 hours. The second night 50minutes and the 3rd night we only had to come back once.
The goal is to teach: "We are here, dont worry. However, you need to sleep alone. But we are here :)"
